# CMake unneeded dependency

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I have a project using 3 CMakeLists.txt:

- CMakeLists.txt **C** is my executable and depends on
- CMakeLists.txt **B** which is a static lib and that depends on
- CMakeLists.txt **A** which is also a static lib and depends on an external lib

In CMakeLists.txt **C** I specify my dependency against **B** using using *target_link_libraries()* and I do the same for the dependency of **B** against **A**. In CMakeLists.txt **A** I specify the dependency against the external lib.

[image: The CMakeLists.txt and dependencies]

I would expect this to work but **C** actually complains at link-time and I can only get it to work by specifying a dependency in **C** against the external lib.

Note that the external lib is dynamic (a .so file).

This looks weird to me, no? Anyone understands what is going on?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. I bet there's a bug in the CMakeLists.txt.

**View real dependencies**

Check it with:

```
cmake .. --graphviz=deps.dot
xdot deps.dot
```

It will show a pretty picture of the dependency tree that cmake sees.

If you don't have xdot, export it to a png:

```
dot -Tpng deps.dot -o deps.png 
firefox deps.png
```

---

**Library not found ?**

Another possibility is that the external library can't actually be found. Use [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) rather than just putting the library name:

```
find_library(FAIL failingmadly)
if (NOT FAIL)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find the failingmadly library")
endif()
target_link_libraries(my_lib_a ${FAIL})
```

---

**Position independent code?**

Another possibility when linking static libs with dependencies on shared libs is the PIC complaints. You could add this in cmake before compiling anything:

```
add_definitions(-fPIC)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi matiu, it did work with find_library() (not sure why though). Is there an equivalent to find_library() to deal with the include directories? Thanks ;)

Comment: no worries :) - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_path.html - also check out: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries